# Laravel blade passing array to controller, but controller reads it as a string

Tags: php, laravel

So here is the first Controller, which gets the data of all the user with an id greater than 1;

```
//UserController
$user = User::where('id','>',1)->get();
return view('user.index', compact('user'));
```

and in the index view it has a button that generates that users data into a report

```
//index.blade.php
<form method="GET" action="/users/{{$user}}/generate">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Generate User Report</button>
</form>
```

when that button is pressed it will send the $user collection into another controller
which does the process of converting it into a report, however the collection of $user is being read as a String instead of an array.

```
return gettype($user); //outputs "String" instead of an array
//return $user will return all of the users data in an array format [{$user data}]
```

Comment: I guess you are misunderstanding the querystring. You can not pass an array in querystring, because, as you can see from its name, is a string.

Comment: why don't you just do like /users/generate and perform the select user inside its own controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass an array in the `querystring`, cause `querystring` is a string.

If you want to pass an array by a form, you have to use `POST` method and hidden elements like this:

```
//index.blade.php
<form method="POST" action="/users/generate">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <input type="hidden" name="users[]" value="{{ $user->id }}" />
    @endforeach
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Generate User Report</button>
</form>
```

Using the square brackets you can get the elements as an array in PHP, in this way (in your controller function):

```
$usersId = $requst->input('users', []);
```